# How do I query complex data in ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have got the following class:

```cs
class Device
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public DeviceType Type { get; set; }
    public Screen Display { get; set; }
}

enum DeviceType 
{ 
    Mobile, Tablet
};

class Screen
{
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

I can insert data by doing so,

```cs
db.Insert(new Device { Name = "IPad2", Brand = "Apple", Price = "£450", Type = DeviceType.Tablet, Display = new Screen { Options = new List<string> { "opt1", "opt2", "opt3"} } });
```

and Display data is added to `Display` column as `{Options:[opt1,opt2,opt3]}`.
Now I cannot get my head around to write a follow query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE Display option "opt1" ;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you want to query server side shouldn't be blobbed. The solution is to refactor them out from the complex type and make them first class Classes/Tables.